Resample ohlc pandas
There is a dataframe with the data specified below.
Datetime as an index
I need to generate a resample of a 3-hour interval, even if there is only 2 hours of data at the end of the day
2024-07-17 09:00:00  1025.6  1025.6  1025.6  1025.6     5343
2024-07-17 10:00:00  1025.4  1026.2  1013.0  1019.4   417547
2024-07-17 11:00:00  1019.6  1038.0  1019.4  1030.6   648291
2024-07-17 12:00:00  1030.2  1039.0  1030.2  1036.2   245209
2024-07-17 13:00:00  1036.0  1038.0  1029.0  1031.2   168755
2024-07-17 14:00:00  1031.2  1034.6  1025.6  1029.4   146726
2024-07-17 15:00:00  1029.6  1036.8  1026.2  1033.8   144680
2024-07-17 16:00:00  1033.8  1047.6  1032.6  1046.6   421860
2024-07-17 17:00:00  1046.2  1051.6  1043.8  1047.4   480781
2024-07-17 18:00:00  1047.6  1047.8  1030.8  1035.6   391968
2024-07-17 19:00:00  1037.2  1044.4  1034.0  1040.0   139914
2024-07-17 20:00:00  1039.8  1040.0  1032.0  1035.2    79836
2024-07-17 21:00:00  1035.0  1040.4  1034.8  1040.0    41185
2024-07-17 22:00:00  1039.8  1043.0  1035.2  1037.0    47903
2024-07-17 23:00:00  1037.0  1037.6  1034.0  1034.6    37957
2024-07-18 09:00:00  1036.2  1036.2  1036.2  1036.2     1403
2024-07-18 10:00:00  1036.2  1043.0  1026.4  1034.0   430315
2024-07-18 11:00:00  1033.8  1034.6  1022.8  1027.2   461764
2024-07-18 12:00:00  1027.2  1038.0  1027.0  1037.0   205564
2024-07-18 13:00:00  1037.0  1042.8  1033.2  1042.2   290967
2024-07-18 14:00:00  1042.2  1047.0  1037.4  1044.6   265148
2024-07-18 15:00:00  1044.2  1047.0  1037.4  1042.4   226078
2024-07-18 16:00:00  1042.2  1056.4  1041.4  1053.2   425763
2024-07-18 17:00:00  1053.6  1060.0  1048.2  1056.8   347094
2024-07-18 18:00:00  1057.2  1065.8  1057.2  1065.6   376461
2024-07-18 19:00:00  1066.0  1070.0  1062.4  1067.4   237408
2024-07-18 20:00:00  1068.0  1069.0  1062.8  1068.4    63951
2024-07-18 21:00:00  1068.4  1070.0  1065.0  1065.8    60839
2024-07-18 22:00:00  1065.8  1070.0  1065.2  1069.4    68737
2024-07-18 23:00:00  1069.0  1069.6  1068.8  1069.0     2421

I need to do a resample starting at 7 a.m.:
    df = df.resample('3H', offset='07h00min').agg(
        {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum'})

At the output, I get the following dataframe:
2024-07-17 07:00:00  1025.6  1025.6  1025.6  1025.6     5343
2024-07-17 10:00:00  3075.2  3103.2  3062.6  3086.2  1311047
2024-07-17 13:00:00  3096.8  3109.4  3080.8  3094.4   460161
2024-07-17 16:00:00  3127.6  3147.0  3107.2  3129.6  1294609
2024-07-17 19:00:00  3112.0  3124.8  3100.8  3115.2   260935
2024-07-18 07:00:00  1036.2  1036.2  1036.2  1036.2     1403
2024-07-18 10:00:00  3097.2  3115.6  3076.2  3098.2  1097643
2024-07-18 13:00:00  3123.4  3136.8  3108.0  3129.2   782193
2024-07-18 16:00:00  3153.0  3182.2  3146.8  3175.6  1149318
2024-07-18 19:00:00  3202.4  3209.0  3190.2  3201.6   362198

As you can see, the data for 22 and 23 pm do not fall into the new dataframe, since there are no full 3 hours. How do I make sure that in any case, data is generated for 22 pm, which will consist only of a 2-hour period?

i cant reproduce your problem. provide print(pd.__version__)

print(pd.version) - 1.5.1

Try running the same code with google colab (pandas 2.0.3), the output is different from yours.

Thank you. The problem was not in the pandas version, but in another part of the code. I was looking for a problem in the wrong place
